Visual Studio Code frequently truncates files when files.autoSave is set to "onFocusChange"
I've had files.autoSave set to "onFocusChange" for over two years now and for all that time, about 1 in 100 saves will result in the file being completely truncated. This almost always happens like this:

I write some code
I hit command-tab to see the change in my browser
The page is blank
I panic
I command-tab back
The file is empty
I hit undo
The code is back

I don't have any particularly exciting extensions here, and even among my various formatters and language servers, this happens on all file types and on all of my computers.
Any ideas on how to debug to the point I could file an intelligible issue, at least?


Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. 2) do you have any different machines that you can reproduce this issue on, or any colleagues that can reproduce the issue with your setup/config?

